# Reversing the digits of an infinite decimal

Tags: limits, real-numbers, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Let $x$ be a real number in $[0,1)$, with decimal expansion
$$
x = 0.d_1 d_2 d_3 \cdots d_i \cdots \;.
$$
If the decimal expansion is finite, ending at $d_i$, then extend with zeros:
$d_k = 0$ for all $k > i$.
Define a sequence $x_k^R$ by digit reversals, as follows:
\begin{eqnarray}
x_1^R & = & 0.d_1 \\
x_2^R & = & 0.d_2 d_1 \\
x_3^R & = & 0.d_3 d_2 d_1 \\
x_4^R & = & 0.d_4 d_3 d_2 d_1 \\
& \cdots &\\
x_k^R & = & 0.d_k d_{k-1} \cdots d_3 d_2 d_1\\
& \cdots &
\end{eqnarray}
Finally, define $x^R = \lim_{k\to\infty} x_k^R$, when that limit exists.

> ***Q.*** For which $x$ does the limit exist?
>   In particular, must $x$ be rational for the limit $x^R$ to exist?
>   If not, what are some irrationals with limits?

If the decimal expansion of $x$ is finite, then the extension by zeros
leads to $\lim_{k\to\infty} x_k^R = 0$.

Comment: It seems pretty clear that the limit can exist if and only if $d_k$ is eventually constant, doesn't it? (This includes the case of being eventually zero.)

Comment: It could also be eventually 9, so you may have two choices.

Comment: Note that even if $d_k$ is not eventually constant, the set $x_k$ can still have a finite number of accumulation points;  in fact, for every rational number, it will have as many accumulation points as there are digits that repeat in the decimal expansion of $x$.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: I do wonder about a sequence of trailing digits that is not quite constant, but increasingly nearly constant... That was behind my question, and perhaps that is your point.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Suppose that $\lim_{k \to \infty} x^R_k = x^R$ exists. Then, for $k$ large enough, the first digit of $x^R_k$ is equal to the first digit of $x^R$, say $a$.

Hence, $d_k = d_{k+1} = \dots = a$ and $x^R = 0.aaaa \dots = a/9$.

So, the number $x$ must have a decimal expansion where eventually only the digit $a$ appears.

Comment: ...and, for completeness, that implies that $x$ is rational.

Comment: but not ALL rationals: only those equal to `m + 1/9*k*(10^-n)` for `m, k, n` positive integer.

Answer (score 15):

The limit exists precisely when the sequence of digits is eventually constant. If it is eventually constantly $d$, the limit is $\frac{d}9$.

Comment: Suppose the sequence is not eventually constant, but rather an increasingly long sequence of constant digits, but with an infrequent blip.

Comment: @Joseph: Then the sequence of reversals won’t converge; see **Crostul**’s proof above. With more information, we can say more. Suppose, for instance, that the mostly constant digit is $d$, and the blips are single digits; then there is some digit $a$ that occurs infinitely often as a blip, the sequence of reversals has one subsequence that converges to $\frac{d}9$ and another that converges to $\frac{a}{10}+\frac{d}{90}$. In particular, it clearly does not converge.

Comment: @Joseph: You’re welcome.